# Clear ROOM Database Entries using Android Studio Database Inspector

Tags: android, android-room

I'm experimenting with `ROOM Database Inspector` on Android Studio.

I *want to clear all entries from the database* using a query on the inspector instead of having to uninstall and then reinstall the app to clear the data.  I also know I could manually clear the cache from AppData but I just need to run a simple query instead of manual spadework.

I saw that I can write a query straight from the Database Inspector but I can't find how or the query to write.
[image]

I also noted the database entries are only **read-only**
[image]

Does anyone know if *it is possible to clear/delete the database using the inspector query*. If so *which query can one use to clear everything off the database using the inspector*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found out that running this command from the Inspector does it.

```
DELETE FROM table_name
```

You only need to click on **Open New Query Tab** and type the above command and then click **Run** button to your right.

[image]

The command clears the database giving you a cleanslate.

Comment: Maybe a full example for the query for better understanding `DELETE FROM user_table WHERE name="Hans"`

Answer (score 3):

You can clear the app database using device file explorer in Android Studio:

```
data -> data-> your app package name -> databases -> database name
```

Comment: Yeah, this is yet another approach.

Comment: Note that with this (useful) answer you lose **the whole database** rather than just the entries - which the orginal post asked for ...